# Change topology with one click?

Tags: topology

Is there a way to quickly change the topology of an object with one click? I found this feature very useful in 3dsMax. Now I'm searching the same in blender.

At 03:15
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpsURXZvcsU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of topology can be made with *[Poke Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#poke-faces)* which will reorient faces as needed and then *[Tris to Quads](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#triangles-to-quads)* will convert triangles to quads oriented as in video.

[image: poking faces]